# Cannot figure out reason for JDOMException SAXBuilder

Tags: json, servlets, saxparser, jdom

I am not able to figure out the reason for JDOMException being caught. I am passing an XML format string to the SAXBulider's build function for getting a Document, an exception is thrown here.

XML String which is stored in String results:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><results><result cover="http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_170/MI0002/213/MI0002213251.jpg?partner=allrovi.com" title="Hey-Ya" artist="A.D.D." year="N/A" genre="Pop/Rock" details="http://www.allmusic.com/album/hey-ya-mw0001029555"/><result cover="http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_170/MI0003/152/MI0003152820.jpg?partner=allrovi.com" title="Heyma" artist="Abir Nasraoui" year="N/A" genre="Latin, Pop/Rock" details="http://www.allmusic.com/album/heyma-mw0002115440"/><result cover="http://cs-server.usc.edu:14186/album.jpg" title="Heyla" artist="Candy" year="2003" genre="R&B" details="http://www.allmusic.com/album/heyla-mw0000698853"/><result cover="http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_170/MI0002/172/MI0002172691.jpg?partner=allrovi.com" title="Heya" artist="Jimmy Stallings" year="2003" genre="International" details="http://www.allmusic.com/album/heya-mw0000336392"/><result cover="http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_170/MI0003/361/MI0003361503.jpg?partner=allrovi.com" title="Heya" artist="David Jones" year="N/A" genre="Electronic" details="http://www.allmusic.com/album/heya-mw0002388044"/></results>
```

And the part of code causing exception is:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

    String temp="";

    out.println("Inside Servlet :::: ");

    try
    {
        out.println("1. HERE");
        Document doc = builder.build(new StringReader(results));
        out.println("2. HERE");
        Element root=doc.getRootElement();
        out.println(root);  
        List resultChildren=root.getChildren();
        out.println("3. HERE");
        if(resultChildren.size()==0)
        {
            out.println("{\"results\":[]}");
            return;
        }           
        temp="{\"results\":{\"result\":[";
        for(int i=0;i<resultChildren.size();i++)
        {
            Element tempElem = (Element)(resultChildren.get(i));

            if(i>0)
            temp+=",";

            if((request.getParameter("type")).equals("Artists"))                    
                 temp+=parseArtists(tempElem);                   
            else if((request.getParameter("type")).equals("Albums"))
                temp+=parseAlbums(tempElem);
            else                    
                temp+=parseSongs(tempElem);                                                         
        }
        temp+="]}}";
    }
    catch(JDOMException ex)
    {
        errors+="1.Could not parse xml file";           
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        errors+="2.Could not parse xml file";           
    }
```

Output generated using PrintWriter is as follows:

```
Inside Servlet :::: 
1. HERE
{"errors": {"1.Could not parse xml file"}}
```

Thus, there is an exception thrown at doc=builder.build(new StringReader(results));

Kindly guide me through this problem.

Comment: Print the stack trace of the exception. The reason of an exception is explained in the exception message. The place where the exception is thrown is in the exception stack trace. Ignoring this information is what prevents you from understanding why you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And after having printed the stack trace (or at least the exception message) you'll see that the input XML is not well formed: There's an attribute containing the string `"R&B"`. Ampersand happens to be one of the few characters that has to be escaped, in this case it should read: `"R&amp;B"`.